# Product topology of two real space

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I am sorry that I know very little in topology. Just would like to ask if  $\mathcal{U}_\alpha\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathcal{V}_\beta\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, is it correct to say that
$$\mathcal{U}_\alpha\times \mathcal{V}_\beta\subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}??$$

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that statement. Incidentally, if $\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}$ and $\mathcal{V}_{\beta}$ are open, then $\mathcal{U}_\alpha\times \mathcal{V}_\beta$ will be open as well.

Comment: yes, both $\mathcal{U}_\alpha$ and $\mathcal{V}_\beta$ are open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how it is related to topology but let me try to answer the question:

**Short answer:** Yes!

**Long answer**: Yes. Well, sort of. Depends on how deep you want to dive into formality. Generally if $X,Y$ are sets and $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ then

$$A\times B\subseteq X\times Y$$

almost by the definition of the Cartesian product. But the problem here is the definition of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. One approach is to define it recursively

$$\mathbb{R}^1=\mathbb{R}$$
$$\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$$

So for example $\mathbb{R}^4=\mathbb{R}\times(\mathbb{R}\times(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}))$. Note the parenthesis.

In that situation $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\neq\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m$ (here "$=$" means the equality of sets) unless $n=1$. However Cartesian product is associative in the following sense:

$$A\times(B\times C)\to (A\times B)\times C$$
$$(a, (b,c))\mapsto ((a, b), c)$$

The mapping above is a bijection, i.e. those sets are equinumerous. This association is so intuitive and well behaving that most of the time we just skip parenthesis and we write $A\times B\times C$. In that sense $\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}\times\mathcal{V}_{\beta}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m=\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.